# How do I parse this function parameter that includes queryselector?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

#### Code Context

We are trying to make our own custom data binding function work. So far, so good, as we got it working, but now we are refactoring.

#### Problem

I am trying to make the constructing of the function a little more user friendly. Currently to invoke it, it looks like this:

```
var obj = new MyBind(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bind="total"]'), 1234);
```

Error:  **Any elements bound are not being updated.**

Ideally, I want to be able to pass a single parameter. But for this first round of refactoring, I want to simply pass the element name. Like this:

```
var obj = new MyBind("total", 1234);
```

#### Failed Efforts

I have tried the following without success:

```
// inside my function
this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-bind="${elements}"]`);
```

#### Live Demo

https://jsbin.com/qakutudole/edit?html,js,output

**Anyone see why this isn't working?**

#### Source Code

Here is the entire function:

```
function MyBind(elements, data) {
        
    this.data = data;
    this.elements = elements;
    //this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-bind="${elements}"]`);
                
    for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
                        
        if(elements[i].tagName == 'INPUT' || elements[i].tagName == 'SELECT' || elements[i].tagName == 'TEXTAREA' ) {
            elements[i].value = data;
        } else if( elements[i].tagName == 'DIV' || elements[i].tagName == 'SPAN' || elements[i].tagName == 'B' ) {
            elements[i].innerHTML = data;
        }
        
        elements[i].addEventListener("change", this, false);
    }
        
}

MyBind.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case "change": this.change(event.target.value);
        
        
    }
};



MyBind.prototype.change = function(value, updateAmounts) {
    
    updateAmounts = typeof updateAmounts !== 'undefined' ? updateAmounts : true;
                        
    this.data = value;
        
    for( var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++ ) {
                
        if(this.elements[i].tagName == 'INPUT' || this.elements[i].tagName == 'SELECT' || this.elements[i].tagName == 'TEXTAREA' ) {
            this.elements[i].value = value;
        } else if( this.elements[i].tagName == 'DIV' || this.elements[i].tagName == 'SPAN' || this.elements[i].tagName == 'B' ) {
            this.elements[i].innerHTML = value;
        }        
        
    }
    
    
    if( updateAmounts === true ) {
        alert("Updating amounts!");
    }
    
};

var obj = new MyBind(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bind="invoice_total"]'), 1234);
//var obj = new MyBind("invoice_total", 1234);
```

Comment: You fail to mention what is not working

Comment: Oh, well the intended result of the function isn't working. Any elements bound are not being updated. Sorry about that.

Comment: There should be a more-or-less obvious error message when you try that. Are you not getting any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to change

```
function MyBind(selector, data) {
//              ^^^^^^^^
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-bind="${selector}"]`);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                            ^^^^^^^^
    this.data = data;
    this.elements = elements;
```

so that the `elements` variable that you use subsequently in the code actually holds the elements, instead of being a string.

Comment: OHHH, so I was passing elements as a string throughout the rest of the code, rather than an array. I see. Great work. Thank you,